# css hack to target both Safari and Chrome SEPARATELY

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I need to target specific CSS styling for various browsers.

I've managed to find a way to target separately:
Firefox only
IE9 only
IE8 only
IE7 only

But... I can't see to target separately Chrome and Safari.  I've found several techniques which work for BOTH Chrome and Safari.  Some techniques are supposed to target one or the other... but they over-ride each other and so the last one applies to both.

I've set up a JS fiddle to show the various techniques, and display the browser match color.  Can anyone help me find the secret to targeting SEPARATELY Safari and Chrome?

http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/MP4qZ/

Here is the CSS:

```
#tester {
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
color: #FFF;
border:#00F solid 4px\9; /* IE8 and below */    
*border:#FF0 solid 4px; /* IE7 and below */
-bracket-:hack(;
    border:#0FF solid 4px;  /* Chrome only*/
);
}
:root #tester{
border:#0F0 solid 4px \0/IE\9; /* IE9 +IE10pp4 */
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() { #tester { border:#F00 solid 4px;  /* Firefox only*/ } }

@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) { #tester { border: #F0F solid 4px; /* Safari */  } }


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
#tester {
    border: #F90 solid 4px; 
}
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<span id="tester">Browser match</span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need some JS:

```
var is_chrome = window.chrome;
var is_safari = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1);

if (is_chrome) {
    $('#tester').addClass('chrome');
}
else if (is_safari) {
    $('#tester').addClass('safari');
}
```

And:

```
#tester.chrome {
   /* your CSS here */
}
#tester.safari {
   /* your CSS here */
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7h5rh/1/

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow Manny! how would need to be changed for this work for Safari?